# How to serialize a specific Id in Django?

Tags: django, django-serializer

I am using the [serialize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder) method to get a json of a Model object. However it does not work when I pass in a specific id.

```
data = serialize('json', Sample.objects.get(id=1), use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
print(data)
```

It seems to only work when you get the entire model's content by `all()` i.e.:

```
data = serialize('json', Sample.objects.all(), use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`filter(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) instead of **`get(...)`** methodas

```
Sample.objects.filter(id=1)
```

ex:

```
data = serialize('json', Sample.objects.filter(id=1), use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no problem with your statements,  check with *filter* option, Instead get() using filter() gives more accurate results.

```
Sample.objects.get(id__exact=14) or
Sample.objects.filter(id__exact=14) or
Sample.objects.filter(id=14) or
Sample.objects.filter(id__in=[14,])
```